# How to assign a variable a float times an integer

Tags: python, python-2.7

Q1 should be able to contain 1.602*10^-19 and Q2: -1.602*10^-19
Instead it gives me a value error: ValueError: invalid literal for float().
What am I doing wroing. I am a beginner by the way.

```
import os
Clear = lambda: os.system("cls")
Clear()
Q1 = float(raw_input("What's Q1?\n"))
Q2 = float(raw_input("What's Q2?\n"))
r = float(raw_input("What's radius?\n"))
def calc(Q1, Q2, r):
    k = 8.99*10**9
    return((k((Q1) * Q2))/r**2)
print(calc(Q1, Q2, r))
```

Comment: While you're playing with numbers, if you are beginning, perhaps [some background concerning floating points](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) could come in handy now or later on.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not say what input you are using or what line you are getting the error, so I am going to assume you are trying to do `float("1.602*10^-19")`.

This is not a valid argument, to need to use a different notation to meet the required format:

```
float("1.602e-19")
```

Comment: I did input the wrong value, but not even 1.602*10 works.

Comment: Ok hold on, I'm dumb, 1.602e-19 is the same thing as 1.602*10^-19. But now there's another problem. I can asign a value to Q1 and Q2 but when I asign the value 0.051 to r it gives me the error float object is not callable

Comment: First of all, that would be a different question. Second of all, are you sure you're even typing `0.051` when you're asked the radius?

Comment: Ye that's another question I guess, ok well thanks a lot I just didn't know how to asign the value correctly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Did you input `1.602*10^-19`?
If so, please note the correct format is  `1.602e-19`

Comment: I did not thanks a lot, but there's another problem not even 1.602*10 works.

Comment: @Snase and when were you even told you should use `1.602*10`? Are you even reading the answers?

Comment: Ok hold on, I'm dumb, 1.602e-19 is the same thing as 1.602*10^-19. But now there's another problem. I can asign a value to Q1 and Q2 but when I asign the value 0.051 to r it gives me the error float object is not callable

Comment: Ok well it works now so thanks a lot for your answers.